# How to load MySQL DB from a dump file in expect script

Tags: mysql, linux, tcl, expect

In order to load a dump file to MySQL database, I have tried the following command many times but it is not working:

```
spawn mysql -u dbUser -h hName -pdbPass dbName < db_schema.sql
```

I got this response:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using
>   readline 6.3 Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
>
> Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]   -?, --help          Display this
>   help and exit.   -I, --help          Synonym for -?   --auto-rehash
>   Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
>                         'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
>                         and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
>                         --disable-auto-rehash.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)   -A, --no-auto-rehash 
>                         No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
>                         table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
>                         mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.   --auto-vertical-output 
>                         Automatically switch to vertical output mode if the
>                         result is wider than the terminal width.   -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
>                         (Enables --silent.)   --character-sets-dir=name 
>                         Directory for character set files.   --column-type-info  Display column type information.   -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
>                         default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
>                         with --comments.   -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.   -#, --debug[=#]     This is a
>   non-debug version. Catch this and exit.   --debug-check       Check
>   memory and open file usage at exit.   -T, --debug-info    Print some
>   debug info at exit.   -D, --database=name Database to use.
>   --default-character-set=name 
>                         Set the default character set.   --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.   --enable-cleartext-plugin 
>                         Enable/disable the clear text authentication plugin.   -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables
>   --force and history
>                         file.)   -E, --vertical      Print the output of a query (rows) vertically.   -f, --force         Continue even if we
>   get an SQL error.   -G, --named-commands 
>                         Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's
>                         internal commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the
>                         named commands can be used from any line of the query,
>                         otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.
>                         Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is
>                         disabled by default.   -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after function names.   --init-command=name SQL Command
>   to execute when connecting to MySQL server.
>                         Will automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.   --local-infile      Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL
>   INFILE.   -b, --no-beep       Turn off beep on error.   -h,
>   --host=name     Connect to host.   -H, --html          Produce HTML output.   -X, --xml           Produce XML output.   --line-numbers
>   Write line numbers for errors.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-line-numbers to disable.)   -L, --skip-line-numbers 
>                         Don't write line number for errors.   -n, --unbuffered    Flush buffer after each query.   --column-names      Write column names in results.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-column-names to disable.)   -N, --skip-column-names 
>                         Don't write column names in results.   --sigint-ignore     Ignore SIGINT (CTRL-C).   -o, --one-database  Ignore statements except those that occur while the
>                         default database is the one named at the command line.   --pager[=name]      Pager to use to display results. If you
>   don't supply an
>                         option, the default pager is taken from your ENV variable
>                         PAGER. Valid pagers are less, more, cat [> filename],
>                         etc. See interactive help (\h) also. This option does not
>                         work in batch mode. Disable with --disable-pager. This
>                         option is disabled by default.   -p, --password[=name] 
>                         Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
>                         not given it's asked from the tty.   -P, --port=#        Port number to use for connection or 0 for default to, in
>                         order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
>                         /etc/services, built-in default (3306).   --prompt=name       Set the mysql prompt to this value.   --protocol=name     The protocol to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe,
>                         memory).   -q, --quick         Don't cache result, print it row by row. This may slow
>                         down the server if the output is suspended. Doesn't use
>                         history file.   -r, --raw           Write fields without conversion. Used with --batch.   --reconnect         Reconnect
>   if the connection is lost. Disable with
>                         --disable-reconnect. This option is enabled by default.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-reconnect to disable.)   -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a
>   tab as separator,
>                         each row on new line.   -S, --socket=name   The socket file to use for connection.   --ssl               Enable SSL
>   for connection (automatically enabled with
>                         other flags).   --ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format (check OpenSSL docs, implies
>                         --ssl).   --ssl-capath=name   CA directory (check OpenSSL docs, implies --ssl).   --ssl-cert=name     X509 cert
>   in PEM format (implies --ssl).   --ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use
>   (implies --ssl).   --ssl-key=name      X509 key in PEM format (implies
>   --ssl).   --ssl-verify-server-cert 
>                         Verify server's "Common Name" in its cert against
>                         hostname used when connecting. This option is disabled by
>                         default.   -t, --table         Output in table format.   --tee=name          Append everything into outfile. See
>   interactive help (\h)
>                         also. Does not work in batch mode. Disable with
>                         --disable-tee. This option is disabled by default.   -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.
>   -U, --safe-updates  Only allow UPDATE and DELETE that uses keys.   -U, --i-am-a-dummy  Synonym for option --safe-updates, -U.   -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).   -V, --version 
>   Output version information and exit.   -w, --wait          Wait and
>   retry if connection is down.   --connect-timeout=# Number of seconds
>   before connection timeout.   --max-allowed-packet=# 
>                         The maximum packet length to send to or receive from
>                         server.   --net-buffer-length=# 
>                         The buffer size for TCP/IP and socket communication.   --select-limit=#    Automatic limit for SELECT when
>   using --safe-updates.   --max-join-size=#   Automatic limit for rows
>   in a join when using
>                         --safe-updates.   --secure-auth       Refuse client connecting to server if it uses old
>                         (pre-4.1.1) protocol.   --server-arg=name   Send embedded server this as a parameter.   --show-warnings     Show
>   warnings after every statement.   --plugin-dir=name   Directory for
>   client-side plugins.   --default-auth=name Default authentication
>   client-side plugin to use.
>
> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>   /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf  The following
>   groups are read: mysql client The following options may be given as
>   the first argument:
>   --print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
>   --no-defaults           Don't read default options from any option file.
>   --defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
>   --defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read.
>
> Variables (--variable-name=value) and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE} 
>   Value (after reading options)
>   --------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- auto-rehash                       TRUE auto-vertical-output              FALSE character-sets-dir
>   (No default value) column-type-info                  FALSE comments
>   FALSE compress                          FALSE debug-check
>   FALSE debug-info                        FALSE database
>   (No default value) default-character-set             auto delimiter
>   ; enable-cleartext-plugin           FALSE vertical
>   FALSE force                             FALSE named-commands
>   FALSE ignore-spaces                     FALSE init-command
>   (No default value) local-infile                      FALSE no-beep
>   FALSE host                              localhost html
>   FALSE xml                               FALSE line-numbers
>   TRUE unbuffered                        FALSE column-names
>   TRUE sigint-ignore                     FALSE port
>   3306 prompt                            mysql>  quick
>   FALSE raw                               FALSE reconnect
>   TRUE socket                            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ssl
>   FALSE ssl-ca                            (No default value) ssl-capath 
>   (No default value) ssl-cert                          (No default
>   value) ssl-cipher                        (No default value) ssl-key
>   (No default value) ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE table
>   FALSE user                              root safe-updates
>   FALSE i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE connect-timeout
>   0 max-allowed-packet                16777216 net-buffer-length
>   16384 select-limit                      1000 max-join-size
>   1000000 secure-auth                       FALSE show-warnings
>   FALSE plugin-dir                        (No default value)
>   default-auth                      (No default value)

**Can any you one help? I think less than symbol "<" doesn't make any sense in expect scripts!!**

Comment: I think it is `-e script.sql`

Comment: like this: `spawn mysql -u dbUser -h hName -pdbPass dbName -e db_schema.sql`, it is not working :/, I got this error `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'db_schema.sql' at line 1`

Comment: Sorry can you tell how dump file was made? Can you display first few lines after cleansing out sensitive info

Comment: its generated by phpMyAdmin. However, I will add it to the question.

Comment: This article http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/import-mysql-dumpfile-sql-datafile-into-my-database/ would agree with you original approach

Comment: Thank you so much @DrewPierce, from the terminal this command works fine: `mysql -u ***** -h **** -p*** dbTestTheTest_V1 < db_schema.sql`, that means the dump file is correct!, and the problem is how to execute the same command in an expect script?

Answer (score 1):

1) Can you make sure there is no space after dash p such as -pPASSWORD

2) can you create a trivial fred.sql that inserts 1 row in some dummy table

3) can you verify that the path to fred.sql is tested if necessary

Fred rules out a problem with your real sql file (i know overkill)

Comment: Thank you so much @DrewPierce, I did all these rules. Actually, I just copied and paste the same command from the terminal to the expect script file and added `spawn` in the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load a dump file to MySQL database then you can use SQL Import Export Wizard as well.

Comment: yes, I know, but how to load the dumps in expect script?